# Can't manage to run a simple angular js example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a very simple angular js sample that doesn't work and I don't understand why.

If anyone sees what I did wrong please let me know, and if not, what steps should I take in order to face it?

this is my index.html:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="/assets/libs/angular-1.4.7.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="example">
This is the index level
<br>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my only view (profile.html):

> This is a profile page

And this is the js file:

```js
var example = angular.module("example", ['ui.router']);

example.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("profile", {
            url: "profile",
            templateUrl: "templates/profile"
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/profile")
});
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
This is the index level
This is a profile page
```

But this is what I get:

> This is the index level

All the js file pathes are correct because I can see them in the developer tool.

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: I think that its not working for you because `templateUrl` isn't correct. Ut should be correct path to a file together with file extension (unless you use something on backend or the template was compiled and named with `templates/profile`) but angular will make an XHR call to get that faile

Comment: Thanks @maurycy I added the file extension and it solved the problem! Please write it again as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that its not working for you because `templateUrl` isn't correct. It should be correct path to a file together with file extension (unless you use something on backend or the template was compiled and named with `templates/profile`) but angular will make an XHR call to get that file

Answer (score 1):

As you have `.otherwise` redirect to `/profile`, you should change you `URL` of state definition to below, so that `ui-router` will loaded the correct state with correct template.

```
$stateProvider
  .state("profile", {
     url: "/profile",
     templateUrl: "templates/profile" //make sure this template has correct path
})
```

Comment: There were actually 2 problems in my code. One is that I missed the slash as you mentioned, and one is that I forgot the file extension as the other guy said. I could only mark one answer as the correct answer but I wouldn't have solved it without your help so thank you so much!